# Is there a way to return true for an empty list in a sort invariant?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

So I am supposed to write a function that returns true if the said sequence is arranged from smallest to largest. I am able to understand strings and num lists but for an empty list, I am unable to understand why it won't return as true.

This is for understanding and possibly help me understand how to manipulate my loops better.

```
def is_sorted(seq):

    for i in range(0, len(seq)):
        if seq[i]<seq[i+1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
print(is_sorted([])) # expected to be true but returns none
```

Comment: `len(seq) = 0` so you do not enter the `for` loop and the function returns `None`. also your function would return `True` for `[0, 1, -1]` (and your list indices go up to `len(seq) + 1`...).

Comment: also the arguments can be string sequences, lists, tuples, as long as there is an index involving them then they can be added to the argument.

Comment: This implementation is wrong. It will return `True` for `[1, 3, 2]` since it only compares the first 2 elements

Comment: unfortunately, i am restricted, and unable to use sorted() as a command, it would defeat the purpose of understanding loops in my course. But I shall take note and utilize this in the future.

@DeepSpace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is wrong. It will return `True` for `[1, 3, 2]` since it only compares the first 2 elements (`return` returns after the first iteration).

It can be fixed by checking for the opposite condition, then `return True` after the loop.

You should also iterate until `len(seq) - 1` otherwise the last iteration will cause an `IndexError`.

```
def is_sorted(seq):
    for i in range(0, len(seq) - 1):
        if seq[i] > seq[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True

print(is_sorted([1, 2, 3]))
# True
print(is_sorted([1, 3, 2]))
# False
print(is_sorted([]))
# True
```

And of course there is the trivial, naive solution,

```
def is_sorted(seq):
    return seq == sorted(seq)
```

Comment: why did you put in ```range(0, len(seq)-1) ```  does that select values from the last index?

Comment: @AshwinSarith it makes the loop iterate until the second-to-last index, otherwise, the last iteration will access a non-existing index. Imagine `seq` having 3 elements (indexes 0, 1 and 2). With `range(0, len(seq))` the last iteration will try to access `seq[i + 1]` (`seq[3]`) which does not exist

Answer (score 3):

The obvious problem is that with an empty list you are returning `None` which evaluates to false. The other problem is that you are using `return` inside of a loop, which means that you aren't evaluating every sequence in the iterable.

@hiro protagonist's answer is one solution to this problem. I offer my alternative using `all` and a generator expression.

```py
def is_sorted(seq):
    return all(seq[i] < seq[i + 1] for i in range(len(seq) - 1))

# All evaluate True
print(is_sorted(['a', 'b', 'c']))
print(is_sorted([1, 2, 3]))
print(is_sorted([]))

# Both evaluate False
print(is_sorted(['a', 'c', 'b']))
print(is_sorted([0, 1, -1]))
```

## Edit with explanation

As best I understand it, `all` works by stepping through an iterable and returns `False` if any value in it evaluates to `False`, otherwise returning `True`.

As the comments may show you, I don't have a good understanding of Python generators. A generator is an iterable object that calculates the next value and yields it back each time it is referenced.

The generator defined above, each time that `all` references it, calculates `seq[i] < seq[i + 1]` and gives that value back. If this is `False` at any time then `all` will return `False`.

I hope this helps. I'm sure one of the good people in the comments will correct any flawed understanding that I have.

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension inside `all`. You can remove the `[ ]` then you don't create a useless list, and use a generator instead

Comment: @DeepSpace, that is true, but I find generator expressions confusing to read. Unless you are very concerned about efficiency I would consider the tradeoff of readability worth it, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: the point of `all` is that it short-circuits; i.e. aborts on the first `False`. therefore you really should use a generator expression (learn to love them! they are great!).

Comment: This is the shortest, but I have not learned how to use all() currently. As a generator expression, does it work by converting every argument into a list? @Jacinator

Answer (score 1):

this is a variant that also works for empty lists and lists of length 1:

```
from itertools import islice

def is_sorted(seq):
    return all(i <= j for i, j in zip(seq, islice(seq, 1, None)))
```

it iterates over `seq[k]` and `seq[k+1]` using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). and only if [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) elements satisfy the requirement `True` will be returned.

Comment: Doesn't the benefit of using `all` with a generator get shadowed by the creation of a new list `seq[1:]`?

Answer (score 0):

Its because for an empty list the code inside the for is not reached. So neither return statement isnt reached. Also you should take into account that a list with only one element should also return True. Solution:

```
def is_sorted(seq):
    for i in range(0, len(seq)-1):
        if seq[i]>=seq[i+1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: thats right, sorry, i assumed OP initial implementation as correct, wich it is not. I'll edit it it now